# Hard SF (not magical) Vampire

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, vampires

I really do not want to do this however after watching Bruce Banner(Marvel Comics) transforms into the incredible Hulk and then revert back to a man form after a while much like a puffer fish ballooning itself to scare off potential predator, I become obsessed to unveil the tricks behind Count Dracula transformation into a bat and vice versa.

Doctor Banner miraculously avoided being pulverized by gamma radiation which is lethal to almost every living organism ever existed on Earth, the side effect is that he flew into rage easily and gains almost infinite strength that allows him to bench press probably even a super massive stellar black hole for warm-up if I'm the editor. (I call this version "Indominus Hulk" when his bones is replaced by adamantium skeleton fused with all Infinity Gems centrifuge.)

Back to Count Dracula's ability to transform into a bat, I need something that can explain the sudden change in body mass when switching between the bat and man forms. Perhaps Count Dracula in his bat form introduce special kind of chemical to dissolve the internal organs and muscle tissues of its victim before sucking them dry, the body instantly store all excess calories as fat and hence that explain its human form which is still problematic.

Unacceptable answers as follows:

1. Magic!
2. consciously manipulate the strong interaction between quarks...alright I'll be lenient but do not go overboard!

Comment: Are we going for conservation of mass or not?

Comment: don't bother to challenge Indominus Hulk, a mutant so strong that black hole spat him back out!

Comment: @Ahriman: yes of course I know it is difficult but you guys can do it can't you?

Comment: One possibility is to make the bat really large, that way it doesn't break the  conversion of mass law

Comment: Not an answer, but an interesting read about the origins of the connection between bats and vampires can be found [here](http://www.ucs.mun.ca/~emiller/bats_vamp_drac.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How could Kuutamian animals work?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/26107/6986).

Comment: Does a 200-lb bat help your question?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: so how does Dracula break into people house? chimney?

Comment: Hi user6760. I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate of a much older question, so I closed it as duplicate. If you feel it isn't, then please [edit] to highlight the differences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The more I think about it, the more I'm convinced that the figure of Count Dracula is a fake. I'm quite certain that we're dealing with a new species of vampire bat. One that likes human blood (coming from certain humans).

To have a better chance at getting what it desires, it has developed a way to move about undetected amongst us. It does this by causing [hallucinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallucination#Visual) in those who hear its ultrasonic cries.

This has the advantage that when it's time to flee it can drop the hallucination, which temporarily confuses the pursuing party and thus gives our bat a chance to escape unscathed.

Comment: great answer! ultrasound wave can penetrate our body heats up blood vessels and body tissues to generate cavitation (small bubbles of air) which could contribute to rupture in the brain cells...

Answer (score 2):

**Why can a vampire change from a man-form to a bat-form?**

Let's draw inspiration from the [mimic octopus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimic_octopus).  It is not a lion fish, a flounder, a sea snake, nor a jelly fish.  But it can imitate those things sufficiently to fool predator and prey.  So perhaps a vampire is neither a man nor a bat, but some creature that can imitate each enough to fool superstitious Carpathian villagers.  (Ok, so there is no such creature that doesn't live in the ocean- but this *is* fiction, right?)

**Why does a vampire drink blood and hate sunlight and so on?**

It has [rabies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire#Rabies).  The virus that causes rabies has mutated within this creature, to the extent that when infected, it displays the behaviors stereotypical of vampires.  This mutation has also made the virus far more virulent, ensuring an epidemic encompassing almost the entire vampire population.

Comment: Note that human-form vampires are sometimes depicted with a cape to the floor, wrapped around their body, either feet nor hands generally visible. That’s a flying head or a head on a stick with a cleverly worn foldable coat, maybe with a relatively huge inflatable sack of air below the neckline. Still a big bat, though.

Answer (score 1):

There's two real challenges here: conservation of mass and conservation of energy.  The latter is particularly important because I think the only real way to manage the conservation of mass is to rebuild yourself from the air from the other side, and that will take some energy.

Let's give this vampire the ability to cut loose molecules of his own body, but capture their binding energy (vampires are not known for giving up anything they can keep hold of).  Perhaps the magical locket around his neck strongly resembles a Rodin coil.  Rodin coils are theorized by their designer to be able to tap into zero point energy, but at the very least we can give them credit for high efficiency resonance which we can use to store energy.

[image: Rodin coil]

So now the vampire can dismiss mass.  He should also be able to regain it on the other side.  He'll have to consume a bunch of gas to make this so.  This might explain why, when Dracula enters the room, the wind rustles through the windows.  Of course, not everything can be gathered from air molecules, but a sizable portion of our mass can.  The remainder may be why he needs the bat form in the first place... it's rich in some of the trace materials we rely on to build ourselves up.  He can do this using the electromagnetic energy stored in his locket.

Of course, there's a lot of information in a human body.  It's brutally difficult to construct one from particles like a 3-d printer because the body isn't quiescent.  Molecules are constantly moving around in the body, so building one up from particles is simply unreasonable.  But guess what... vampires aren't alive.  In exchange for the loss of a beating heart, a vampire's body is now a dead walking corpse, with a lot less information content and total quiescence because nothing is living!  No human could ever accomplish this man to bat to man feat, but a living dead vampire could!

Reality check? Maybe.  I had to invoke an "alternative physics" developer's invention, 3d printing of bodies, and a body that's literally "on the wind."  But you never know.

Comment: This is a really great answer however since this is a public faq unfortunately I have to follow the crowd. Majority wins! anyway thanks.+1

Comment: @user6760 You can always accept whatever answer you want.  Though with the votes as they are, there's a clear crowd favorite.  I actually prefer the hallucination approach myself because there's *scores* of vampire specific lore tidbits that can be explained really well that way, but I didn't see it as a valid approach given the question wording.  That and I just discovered Rodin coils, and I really want to share them... that way someone else can figure out his "math" and explain it to me rather than having to slog through his ideas and sort the wheat from the chaff =p

Answer (score 0):

I could see a creature with an [Ant-Man or Wasp - style suit or capability to decrease the size](http://www.wired.com/2015/07/ant-man-shrinks-by-stretching-into-other-dimensions/), becoming more dense when it transforms. This could be a biological creature or a collection of microbots that can shift forms... or [some combination of both](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Teselecta).

Comment: In before Pym creates a blackhole by accident.